# Get values checked

Tags: php

I am having trouble in getting checked values checked in form. I was trying to use the same function as I have used to insert values to print all values in edit form, and which are in other table inserted to mark them checked.
Function to insert values in database table in insert form and it works.

```
 function emarketing_usluge(){
        $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        $link->set_charset("utf8");
        $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `jos_ib_emarketing_oprema` order by OpremaId asc  ");

        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="usluge[]" value="'.$record['OpremaId ']. '">' . $record['OpremaNaziv'] . ' <br/><br/> </input>';
        }
    }
```

In this function I get list of all services and place them in checkboxes. 
Now I want to edit form, and display all values that are checked by using same function.

First I make query to get values, I am using here pdo but for funcion files I have used mysqli.

Form for editing!

```
 $sql_oprema = "SELECT a.Partner, a.OpremaId, a.Oprema, b.OpremaNaziv
                       FROM jos_ib_emarketing_stavke_oprema a
                       join jos_ib_emarketing_oprema b
                       on OpremaId = b.Oprema
                       WHERE a.Partner= $id";           
 $oprema = $conn->query($sql_oprema);
 $row = $oprema ->fetch();

 <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input type="checkbox" id="oprema" onclick="Exposeoprema()">Oprema<br>
       <div id="Scrolloprema" style="height:150;width:200px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid blue;display:none">
       <?php
          while($row = $oprema ->fetch()) {
          $data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]"   value="'.$row["Oprema"].'"';
          if(isset($row['Oprema'])) {//field in the database
          $data.=' checked="checked';
         }
        $data.='">'. $row["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
     }
        emarketing_oprema($data);
    ?>   
      </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying print all service values by using function, but the ones that are checked they need to have check mark. I am getting problem and could not figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: Is it me or you are not SELECTing the `checked` column in your query?

Comment: In  function emarketing_usluge I am selecting all values from table and place them in checkbox, so multiple values could be selected. In edit form I am selecting selecting values that are checked and joining other table

Answer (score 1):

Looking back to your SQL query, I don't see an extraction of checked field, you are not selecting it. So there is never going to be a $row['checked'] element of your query.

You should add:

```
 $sql_oprema = "SELECT a.checked, a.Partner, a.OpremaId, a.Oprema, b.OpremaNaziv
                   FROM jos_ib_emarketing_stavke_oprema a
                   join jos_ib_emarketing_oprema b
                   on OpremaId = b.Oprema
                   WHERE a.Partner= $id";
```

Comment: I made mistake it is $row['Oprema?] not  $row['checked'] thanks for helping but still it does not work

Comment: Have you tried printing the result of the query for debugging purposes? print_r($row) and see what results are fetched. One more thing that I've noticed: Look at your join condition, if you have OpremaId on both tables, then the OpremaId in **on OpremaId = b.Oprema** would be ambigious. Try **on a.OpremaId = b.Oprema**

Comment: Now that the `$row['checked']` stuff has disapperaed from your code you still have the very same behaviour? Or anything changed? I do agree with @Suat, I would be surprised if your query were to give you _any_ result, it should end up with a "ambiguous column" error. Can you provide us a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to understand better what's going on?